# Royal Enfield Classic 350: Dislocating Carburetor Clamp

Tags: motorcycle, carburetor, enfield-classic, royal-enfield

I own a classic 350. While starting my vehicle, sometimes the carburetor hose becomes disconnected from the mounted clamp area.

Has anyone faced this issue? If you have, please help me out.

Comment: When you say hose, are you talking about the rubber boot between the carb and the head? Is the carb pulling out of it? https://s11.postimg.org/q5ufivair/carb_boot_crack.jpg

Comment: Sounds like a loose or broken clamp. More details would be very helpful.